# Python type hint return of None in method signature - is it useful?

Tags: python, static-analysis, type-hinting, nonetype, mypy

When Python methods have no `return` statement, they return `None`.  I have seen a few cases where the method's return of `None` is type annotated via `-> None`.

Is there any advantage to this?  Do any static type checkers actually use this explicit type annotation?

Or (since return of `None` is probably assumed by static type checkers), is it just unnecessary additional text?

---

**Code Sample**

```py
def print_hi():
    print("hi")
```

VS

```py
def print_hi() -> None:
    print("hi")
```

Comment: This is a good question. I wouldn't use it personally, but maybe there are good reasons to do this.

Comment: It's as useful as any other return type hint: it says that `print_hi` is *supposed* to return `None`, no matter what you might end up *trying* to return.

Comment: Lacking a return type annotation, static type checkers should make *no* assumptions about what the function should or should not return.

Comment: Yes @Georgy it seems I have made a duplicate question.  I marked this as a duplicate.  I wish that other question's wording was better, cuz I searched around for some time before asking this.

Comment: Also, @chepner, I agree with what you said, and it also agrees with the answer for the question linked